# Unable to return to the desired URL or view of the JSP

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function setHiddenVal(){
      var goAhead = true;
      var myVal="I am hidden value";                
        document.getElementById("secretValue").value = myVal;
        if (goAhead == true) {
        document.forms["register-form"].submit();
      }
      }
      </script> 
     </head>
     <body>
<!--Main Container Starts here-->
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="header">            
        <div class="right_panel">
            <h2 align="center"><u>User Master</u></h2>                      
                <div class="top-form">
                <div>
                  **<form:form action="/usermaster" modelAttribute="CustomerForm" id="register-form" method="POST">**
                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="" class="form1">

                        <tr>
                                <td class="label">Name:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input path="firstname"/>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="label">Password:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input path="password"/>
                                </td>

                        </tr>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

             <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" class="btn blue px16" value="Search" />
                                <input type="button" name="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="setHiddenVal();"/>
                                <input type="button" class="btn blue px16" value="Clear" />                             
                                <input type="button" class="btn blue px16" value="Change Password" />               
                                <input type="button" class="btn blue px16" value="Manage User Notification Profile" />              
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                   </div>
                </form:form>


                 </div> 
             </div>                                                
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


so above one is my code for jsp and below is the code of controller



    @RequestMapping(value={"/usermaster" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public  final String addUserMaster(@ModelAttribute("CustomerForm") CustomerForm pricing, Map<String, Object> map,
                 Model model,  HttpServletRequest request) {
 System.out.println("the first name is "+pricing.getFirstname());
 System.out.println("the password is "+pricing.getPassword());
  return "usermaster";
           }

@RequestMapping(value={"/showusermaster" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String showPage(ModelMap model){
      model.addAttribute("CustomerForm", new CustomerForm());
      return "usermaster";
      }
```

But my page gets open up using a popup with the url:

```
C:\Users\ganganshu.s\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\YW6383E8\usermaster
```

so it should open like

```
http://localhost:8080/enbee/usermaster
```

Could you please tell me what should I put in the form action.. as I think some mistake is there in the form action does in spring MVC we put the action like in the case I  mentioned above.

Spring confg file is given below :

```
    <mvc:interceptors> 
<bean class="com.enbee.admin.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
```

```
<!-- Declare a view resolver-->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1" />
```

and the jsp name is usermaster.jsp

and in the sidemenu.jsp I have changed to this :

```
 <li><a href="<c:url value='/showusermaster'/>">User Master</a></li>
```

Comment: please format your question correctly and try to provide a minimal example (i.e. don't post code that is not related to the issue).

Comment: are u able to understand my question now

Comment: please post your Spring configuration files as well. What is the name of file the form is in? Can you open `http://localhost:8080/enbee/usermaster`? If yes, what is the result?

Comment: also please write more about when and how your error happens.

Comment: If I am trying to open http://localhost:8080/enbee/usermaster it is saying "do you want to open or save from localhost" yes/no if i click on yes than it will say by which program u want to open it then I wil select IE.at that point of time it wil open it from the link c://....usermaster.

Comment: it printing usermaster only..

Comment: do you have `@RequestMapping` annotation on your controller class also?

Comment: No..because in my controller class other functions are also there.

Comment: Any idea why its behaving like this.. where I need to do the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `method` parameter of `RequestMapping` annotation to `RequestMethod.POST`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usermaster", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String addUserMaster(...){
...
}
```

so that when you submit your form to the URL `/usermaster` using `method="POST"` this method will get executed.

You also need to have a method (mapped to an URL) that will show this page to the user. You can use a method as below for this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showusermaster", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(ModelMap model){
model.addAttribute("CustomerForm", new CustomerForm());
return "usermaster";
}
```

With this method in place, the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/enbee/showusermaster
```

will show the `usermaster.jsp` page to the user. Now when you submit this `form`, the above `addUserMaster` method will be invoked.

You don't have to create new jsp file. The url `/showusermaster` will return the `usermaster.jsp` to the user, where the user can add form values and submit the form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
...
<c:url var="submitUrl" value="/usermaster">
<form:form id="form" action="${submitUrl}" modelAttribute="CustomerForm" method="POST">
```

Now when the user clicks on the submit button, this form will be submitted to `/usermaster` URL and will be handled by `addUserMaster` method.

Comment: I am getting this message "request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: and if I am adding RequestMethod.GET so the same problem persist.

Comment: so do i need to create a new jsp with name showusermaster or how i have to map showusermaster to a jsp..Could you please explain.

Comment: what changes I need to do in JSP can you please explain.

Comment: You are Correct... but I am getting HTTP:Status 505 Get method doesn't supported.

Comment: but I think this statement @RequestMapping(value = "/usermaster", method = RequestMethod.GET)
should be @RequestMapping(value = "/showusermaster", method = RequestMethod.GET) that means instead of showusermaster it shoule be usermaster

Comment: you can use any name for the mapping URL. The point is that, you need one URL for GET request which will show the page to the user, and one URL to post the form data.

Comment: yes pabitra u are right I tried it but again the pop up window problem still there..are you sure like these lines <li><a href="<c:url value='/showusermaster'/>">User Master</a></li> and the above form action line are correct one..

Comment: you need to add `new CustomerForm()` attribute to the model (as shown in my answer). and if you want place any other code, you can do that, as it is just another java method.

Comment: sorry for late comment, but I am unable to get why it is opening the view from here :C\Users\ganganshu.s\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\YW6383E8\usermaster instead of opening from here http://localhost:8080/enbee/usermaster.

Comment: try removing the two `**` from around the `<form>` tag and use the `<form>` tag as shown in my answer.

Comment: @user2893700 You should add what you've tried into the question instead of the comments, you're more likely to get an answer if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the content type returned by your controller method, adding `produces = "text/html"` param to your `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: still getting the same problem.

Comment: what happens if you add `@ResponseBody` annotation just below `@RequestMapping`? this annotation means that the String that you return from function should be interpreted as response instead of being interpreted as a view name.

Comment: it printing simply a string usermaster only

Comment: ok, that was expected. That means there is problem with how the view name is resolved. I would suggest to follow @Debojit Saikia's answer, I would do it the same way.